# Unable to connect the OpenVpn client to OpenVpn Server

Tags: openvpn

I am trying to connect the OpenVPN client to the OpenVPN server and unfortunately, I got the below error and it continuously reconnecting again after few seconds. Can anyone please help me out from this.

```
Fri Mar 20 13:53:30 2020 45.115.104.77:63610 VERIFY ERROR: depth=0, error=unsupported certificate purpose: C=US, ST=CA, L=SanFrancisco, O=OpenVPN, OU=changeme, CN=changeme, name=changeme, emailAddress=mail@host.domain
Fri Mar 20 13:53:30 2020 45.115.104.77:63610 OpenSSL: error:1417C086:SSL routines:tls_process_client_certificate:certificate verify failed
Fri Mar 20 13:53:30 2020 45.115.104.77:63610 TLS_ERROR: BIO read tls_read_plaintext error
Fri Mar 20 13:53:30 2020 45.115.104.77:63610 TLS Error: TLS object -> incoming plaintext read error
Fri Mar 20 13:53:30 2020 45.115.104.77:63610 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
Fri Mar 20 13:53:30 2020 45.115.104.77:63610 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, client-instance restarting
```

> Client-Side file is : (.ovpn)

```
client
dev tun_c_ovpn
proto udp
remote ***.***.**.** 1194
resolv-retry infinite
keepalive 5 10
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
verb 3
remote-cert-tls server
ns-cert-type server

<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
Added
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>

<cert>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
Added
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>

<key>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
Added
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----

</key>
```

> Server Side File (.ovpn)

```
port 1194
proto udp4
dev tun
ca "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\ca.crt"
cert "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\ServerVPN.crt"
key "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\ServerVPN.key"
dh "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\dh2048.pem"
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
verb 3
explicit-exit-notify 1
client-config-dir "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\ccd"
ifconfig-pool-persist "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\log\\ipp.txt" 5
```

Comment: `unsupported certificate purpose`: your certificate is not suitable for this. Create a correct certificate. It's [documented in great detail](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/how-to/#setting-up-your-own-certificate-authority-ca-and-generating-certificates-and-keys-for-an-openvpn-server-and-multiple-clients).

Comment: Can you please tell me, In Client configuration file we have to set the certificates i.e `<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>

<cert>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>

<key>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----

-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>` . So which certificates I have to fill in these three areas (Server-side or client-side) ??